# Extracting last item from string in foreach loop

Tags: foreach

I'm working on matrix that contains the name of a class, but sometimes the class name is very long and I only need two last sections of name.

I have string containing some text, separated with '.', and I need to extract last two text.

For example:

string : af.bf.cf.df.ef
my needed value : df.ef

I wrote some code, but it's not working:

```
string[] split1 = "af.bf.cf.df.ef";
foreach (string item in split1)
{
 string myvalue = item;
}
```

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string[] list  = "1.2.3.4.5".Split('.');
 string last2 = list[ list.count - 2] + "." + list[ list.count - 1];
```